How to calculate a sample size for non inferiority test two samples?
I have a test where I want to check whether the install rate of tests group is at least 70% of controls group. To do so I took the following function from Python libraries
alpha = 0.1  
power = 0.80
p_A = 0.0056    # control group install rate

effect_size = sms.proportion_effectsize(p_A, p_A * 0.7)  # 70% of control

# Step 2: Calculate sample size per group with a one-sided (non-inferiority) test
sample_size = sms.NormalIndPower().solve_power(
    effect_size, 
    power=power, 
    alpha=alpha, 
    ratio=1, 
    alternative='larger'  # one-tailed test for detecting p_B >= 70% * p_A
)

I got around 15000 for a sample size. But when I run the test after gathering the results. It fails to detect the difference between tests and controls IR when tests IR is 85% of controls. I can't understand why it doesn't see the difference if its big enough.
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.stats.api as sms

# Example: Assume these are your data
x_test = 80    # Number of installs in test group
n_test = 15015   # Sample size in test group
x_control = 101  # Number of installs in control group
n_control = 15015  # Sample size in control group

# Step 1: Observed proportions
p_test = x_test / n_test
p_control = x_control / n_control

x_control = p_control * n_control * 0.7

# Step 2: Conduct the z-test for proportions
stat, p_value = sms.proportions_ztest([x_test, x_control], [n_test, n_control], alternative='larger')

# Step 3: Output the result
print(f"Z-statistic: {stat:.4f}, p-value: {p_value:.4f}")

# Decision based on p-value
alpha = 0.05
if p_value < alpha:
    print("Reject the null hypothesis: Test group's rate is significantly greater than 70% of control group's rate.")
else:
    print("Fail to reject the null hypothesis: No significant difference found.")

I've tried to calculate the sample size with z test and the results as well

I think the problem you are having is to do with the effect size and the comparison.
effect_size = sms.proportion_effectsize(p_A, p_A * 0.7)  # 70% of control is getting the effect sizes between the control and 70% of the control.
In your test you are then doing the significance testing on x_test and 70% of the control. Not the original control and x_test which is what you are doing in the effect size section. So if you omit the line x_control = p_control * n_control * 0.7 in your code you will see you are very close to the significance at 95%.
What I think you were trying to do was compare the x_test to 70% of the control, so you your effect size needs to be the prediction of to 70% of the control. In this instance: effect_size = sms.proportion_effectsize(p_A * 0.7 , x_test)
Does that make sense? I've been struggling with non-inferiority tests recently too

Hi! Sorry, don't quite get it still:( So you're offering to compare test proportion with the initial controls one (not multiplied by 70%)? My task is to choose the tests which are at least 70% of controls, and if i omit the 70% part then p-value for the case above will be much higher than 0.1.
As I see it my H0 is 0.7p1>p2, and Ha 0.7p1<=p2

When I run the code above without reclassifying x_control I get p-value 0.9413 which is higher than 0.1 alpha but this could be due to control rate changing. In the power analysis it is 0.0056 and in the test control is 0.0067.
OK so I think if those are your hypotheses, then I still think the effect size you are trying to detect is effect_size = sms.proportion_effectsize(p_1 * 0.7 , p2) ?
As your hypothesis does not include normal p1 anywhere so it should not be used in the effect size for the sample size? What do you think?
